# C kernel- printing string not working

Tags: c, kernel

I am making a C kernel from scratch, and I literally just copied this code off of a website because my code wasn't working so I was confused.

```
void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "my first kernel";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins here.
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;

    /* this loops clears the screen
    * there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
        /* blank character */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        /* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x07;         
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* this loop writes the string to video memory */
    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        /* the character's ascii */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        /* attribute-byte: give character black bg and light grey fg */
        vidptr[i+1] = 0x07;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    return;
}
```

When I run my kernel, it prints an S to the screen and nothing else. I know my kernel is booting, because if I do

```
vidptr[0] = 'h';
vidptr[2] = 'e';
vidptr[4] = 'l';
vidptr[6] = 'l';
vidptr[8] = 'o';
```

it works as expected. What is happening?

EDIT: It might be something with my code that loads the kernel (might not have set up some of the registers) so I will just look into grub and other things.

Comment: What is a C kernel? C is just a programming language

Comment: That is why you don't copy code with the intention to learn anything.

Comment: @StefanFalk Sorry I wasn't clear, I have been working on my kernel for a bit, and when I tried to make a print function I couldn't get it to work, so I went to a website to try code to see if it was just my code.

Comment: It's not possible that it's working with the values you store in the array `'0' != '\0'`.

Comment: @iharob Yeah, that's what I think too. If I just do vidptr[0] = str[0]; it doesn't work.

Comment: @EdHeal Definition of a kernel: the most basic level or core of an operating system of a computer, responsible for resource allocation, file management, and security.

Comment: @user3042719 - So where does the C programming language fit into that definition

Comment: @EdHeal You can make a kernel in almost any language, I just chose C.

Comment: Does the clear screen loop work as expected?

Comment: @Abhinav Yes it does.

Comment: I am not sure if it is GRUB, as long as you are booting in Real Mode, this should work. Have you tried interrupt functions etc, BIOS calls?

Comment: @Abhinav I am in 32 bit protected mode.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the volatile keyword with the variable

Ref page: http://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen

```
// note this example will always write to the top
// line of the screen
void write_string( int colour, const char *string )
{
    volatile char *video = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
    while( *string != 0 )
    {
        *video++ = *string++;
        *video++ = colour;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if I use `char str[] = "blabla";` instead of `char *str = "blabla";` it works.

Comment: I get a linker error `undefined reference to '__stack_chk_fail'` if I do this :/

Answer (score 0):

First, have you set the SP before jumping Kernel or before running the function? If you have not, please set them appropriately. In your starting function you should set the stack pointer DS, SS; you can use inline assembly at the beginning of the program. Also instead `char * p = "Something"` you should use `char var [] = "Something"`, or

```
char var[10]; 
var[1] = 'S'; 
var[2] = 'o';
```

or

```
 char var[] = { 'S', 'o', 'm', 'e', ..., '\0' } ;
```

My bootloader establishes the GDT and makes the switcthing to 32 bit mode and jumps (`jmp 0x8:0x8000`) Here `0x8` is my Code segment address in GDT, 0x10 for the  DS, SS; so it jumps to kernel. Before I hadn't set the SS, SP, DS and I could not get it printed so I have written this small code:

```
[bits 32]

 MOV   AX, 0x10 ; 0x10 points at the new data selector
 MOV   DS, eax
 MOV   ES, AX
 MOV   FS, AX
 MOV   GS, AX
 MOV   SS, AX
 MOV  eax, 0x200000
 MOV  esp, eax
```

and compiled it with `nasm` and added to beginning of the kernel program manually by using a HEX editor program.

Comment: Please format your code sections properly in future.